# Separate customizations according to modes

Tags: init-file, customize

Using emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04.

I have customized several variables using `M-x customize-variable`. So, there is a large `custom-set-variables` section at the very beginning of my `init.el`. Moreover, there are several key-bindings, etc. in the same file.

Now, I want to separate my customizations across different files. So, all org-related customizations (variables and key-bindings) will go in `org-settings.el`, etc.

So, I created `org-settings.el` with the

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-agenda-follow-indirect t)
 '(org-agenda-show-inherited-tags nil)
 '(org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
 '(org-agenda-span (quote day))
)
;; Useful key bindings
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
```

In my `init.el` I then added `(load "org-settings.el")`.

Funny thing is, every time I restart emacs, all org custom variables from `org-settings.el` are copied back to `init.el`.

How do I solve this? I would love to have a clean `init.el`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be possible with an extra package.

### Initsplit

[Initsplit](https://github.com/dabrahams/initsplit) (initially written by John Wiegley — one of the co-maintainers of Emacs) was designed for exactly this purpose. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be [actively maintained](https://github.com/dabrahams/initsplit/issues/18#issuecomment-252502952), but it still works and appears to be used by people. Also unfortunately it's not on ELPA or MELPA, so you'll need to download it manually.

In a terminal:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.emacs.d/lisp/
cd ~/.emacs.d/lisp/
git clone https://github.com/dabrahams/initsplit
```

and add the following to your `init.el`:

```elisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/initsplit/")
(require 'initsplit)
```

(Obviously, you could download `initsplit.el` by some other method and you could place it wherever you wish.)

Now you need to configure `initsplit` to place your `org`-related customisations in the right place, which is done by setting the value of `initsplit-customizations-alist` (it has a relatively comprehensive docstring). This can be done either with `setq` or via `customize`, as for most variables.

As stated in the docstring, `initsplit-customizations-alist` should be a list of lists of the form:

```elisp
'((REGEXP1 FILE1 BYTECOMP PRE-LOAD)
  (REGEXP2 FILE2 BYTECOMP PRE-LOAD)
  [...] )
```

I haven't managed to get the automatic "pre-load" to work and byte-compiling "customize" is probably overkill, so I recommend setting the two last elements to nil. In your case, assuming that you only want to separate out `org`-related customizations, and that you used customize, you should have the following lines in your main `custom-set-variables` block:

```elisp
'(initsplit-customizations-alist
  (quote
   (("\\`org-" "~/.emacs.d/lisp/org-settings.el" nil nil))))
```

(The escaped backquote in the "\\`org-" regexp is used for matching only the start of the variable name, so that, say `foobar-org-variable` isn't matched.)

Finally, you need to ensure that `lisp/org-settings.el` is loaded (though again obviously you can use whatever paths you wish):

```elisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
(load "org-settings")
```

### Alternatives (`use-package` with `:custom`)

If you use [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package), you could try moving the relevant variables to a section of the form:

```elisp
(use-package org
  :custom
  (org-agenda-follow-indirect t)
  (org-agenda-show-inherited-tags nil)
  (org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
  (org-agenda-span (quote day)))
```

However, this has the considerable disadvantage that if you make further customisations, with `customize-variable`, these will still be added to the main `custom-set-variables` block (and these changes might not have a permanent effect...).

[Here](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/517) there is some discussion on combining `use-package`'s `:custom` with `initsplit`, to overcome the disadvantage, but it hasn't been integrated into `use-package`.

### More alternatives

You may already be aware of this, but there's an option to save *all* (unfortunately) your customizations in a file other than `.emacs`/`init.el`:

```elisp
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs-custom.el")
(load custom-file)
```

In this case, your customizations would be sourced from and saved to `~/.emacs-custom.el`, rather than from the init file. (Example taken [from the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Customizations.html), which has some further details.)

This has the advantage that your init file would be kept clean, but the disadvantage that your customizations would not be grouped by package/mode/topic but still clumped all together.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my configuration:

```
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/garbage.el")
```

and I *don't* `(load custom-file)` at all. Instead, I use the
customize interface to try out new settings, but whenever I decide to
keep a customization I put it by hand in the proper spot in my
`init.el`.